# Replace a selection of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Dataset value_counts()]

I'm trying to do clean a data set, fill missing values, etc.
I noticed that for "sex", some values are missing and instead of just filling the missing values with whatever is the most frequent, I want to fill the missing values with a ratio of males to females.

The following does not work, but is as close as I've gotten so far.
`CleanedDF[CleanedDF['sex'] == 'NA'][:1000].replace('NA', 'Female', inplace=True)`

Unfortuantely, when I run `len (test[CleanedDF['sex'] == 'NA'])`, I can see that my original dataset is unchanged. I learned that this is because its creating a copy of the DF and updating that.

I've also tried, to no avail: `CleanedDF.loc[CleanedDF['sex'] == 'NA', 'sex'][:1035] = 'Female'`

Comment: `CleanedDF['sex'].isna()` may solve your problem on getting indices of NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `np.nan` and `fillna` with `limit`:

```
CleanedDF['sex'] = CleanedDF['sex'].replace('NA', np.nan).fillna('Female', limit=1000)
```

Incase you want to change `NaN` back to `NA`, try:

```
CleanedDF['sex'] = CleanedDF['sex'].replace('NA', np.nan).fillna('Female', limit=1000).fillna('NA')
```

Comment: What if I wanted to do it without .fillna()?   

I only used 'NA' in this example, but there are other columns that I need to do the same thing with, and I check it against .isin(MissingEntries) where MissingEntries = ['Missing', 'Unkown', 'NA', np.nan]

Comment: For this column, filllna with limit will work, so I appreciate the answer.